# Why result.Succeeded return failed in ASP Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

When trying to add the ability to add a name during registration, an error occurred when logging into the account. When I register, the login is successful, but as soon as I log out and try to log in again, the login error

**Changes made to the log file**

```
            var user = CreateUser();
            await _userStore.SetUserNameAsync(user, Input.UserName, CancellationToken.None);
            await _emailStore.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.Email, CancellationToken.None);
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, Input.Password);
```

Here in UserNameAsync the standard value of the email, I will change it to the username

**Part when where error**

```
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded) //Return failed
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Page();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the EmailConfirmed Colum if it has a value in your database,
If you registed with your e-mail,an e-mail will be sent to you to comfirm.and your error may  caused by it.

You could also try to set as follow in your startup class to avoid the error

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                ....
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
                ....
             });
```